# Having trouble understanding how to add objects to a dynamic array and printing them in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, object

I'm trying to test code to create a dynamic array that accepts Objects of different types from a phonebook2.txt file. I'm currently having trouble understanding why the code won't run. I'm getting a lot of error messages after I tried adding the printMyArray method. Any help would be awesome.

I know how to do this using vectors, but I have to create a dynamic array using the new operator.

```
/*PATRICIA JOHNSON 973437
LINDA WILLIAMS 3532665
BARBARA BROWN 4059171
ELIZABETH JONES 2736877
JENNIFER MILLER 3863726
MARIA DAVIS 6297086
SUSAN GARCIA 6063076
MARGARET RODRIGUEZ 350662
DOROTHY WILSON 2829644
LISA MARTINEZ 6299105*/
```

```
class Contact {
    private:
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        int phoneNumber;

    public:
        Contact(){};
        Contact(string, string, int);

        string getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        string getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        int getPhoneNumber() const {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
}
```

```
#include "Contact.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void printMyArray(Contact* arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        cout << arr[i].getFirstName() << " " << arr[i].getLastName() << " " << arr[i].getPhoneNumber() << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    Contact *contactsArray = new Contact[50];
    ifstream inFile("phonebook2.txt");

    int i;

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int pnum;

    while (inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> pnum) {
        cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << pnum << endl;
        Contact c(firstName, lastName, pnum);
        contactsArray[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        cout << contactsArray[i] << endl;
    }
    
    printMyArray(contactsArray);

    delete[] contactsArray;
    
    return 0;
}

Some error messages: 

main.cpp:24:5: error: 'printMyArray' was not declared in this scope
     printMyArray(contactsArray);

undefined reference to `Contact::Contact(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Describe the problem.  "Don't run" is not sufficient.  Regarding error messages, even if you don't want to read them, that does not mean they are unimportant.  Error messages will tell us what the problem is without needing to read your code.  You also mentioned that problems started happening after adding `printMyArray` method, yet inexplicably you have not included this method in your question and the code you have shown does not call it.

Comment: "I'm getting a lot of error messages after I tried adding the printMyArray method" If you want help with this, then you need to *show us a version of the code that includes this method, along with the attempt to use it*.

Comment: But in any case, you should make sure first that the method works correctly with, for example, a single `Contact` instance declared locally, without any attempt to use arrays (either dynamic or static). Before you can fix a problem, you need to *find it*.

Answer (score 0):

Model a structure to your input:

```
struct Record
{
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  string phone_number;
};
```

Next, overload the `operator>>` to read a `Record` from the input stream:

```
    struct Record
    {
      string first_name;
      string last_name;
      string phone_number;
      friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
    };
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.first_name;
  input >> r.last_name;
  input >> r.phone_number;
  input.ignore(1000000, '\n');
  return input;
}
```

Read in your records into a database:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (input_file >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

Simplify your life, don't use static arrays or dynamic arrays.  The `std::vector` is an array that will resize as necessary.  You don't need to write code to allocate an array, check for overflow, allocate new array, copy old array to new array, delete old array.